# Center css background image if image wider than container

Tags: css, background-image

Using the css background-image property is it possible to center the image in a container narrower than the image width?

```
<div style = "background-image:url('a_1600pxwide_image') repeat-y center top">
    <!-- div less than 1600px -->
</div>
```

Comment: did you try `background: url('a_1600pxwide_image') center center;`?

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is wrong. Maybe You meant `background` property, and not `background-image`. By the way, using `background` you can center a bigger background image with a syntax like that:

```
background: url('a_1600pxwide_image') center center;
```

[Example JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yuqeculunige/1/edit)